# How do I list a Subversion repository's ignore settings?

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repository I set up a long time ago. I don't remember exactly what files I specified to be ignored, and I can't find documentation on how to display the ignore settings I set.

How can I find these settings?

This is on my [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I view all ignored patterns set with svn:ignore recursively in an svn repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252270/how-do-i-view-all-ignored-patterns-set-with-svnignore-recursively-in-an-svn-rep)

Comment: Please, also keep in mind a file or directory may be tracked by SVN, although it may look to be ignored by an svn:ignore or svn:global-ignores. That was not the question, but to know what is indeed ignored, the best is to do a `svn ls -R .` then a `ls -R` and compare both.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

List all properties recursively on all files:

```
svn proplist -v -R [TARGET]
```

You could also send the output in a file to find any `svn:ignore` property:

```
svn proplist -v -R [TARGET] > file.log
```

Comment: +1 and accepted answer because of -R which gets me all the settings!

Answer (score 35):

```
svn proplist -v -R mylocalfolder/ | grep svn:ignore -B 1
```

This is your answer dunxd. Left hand side will list all props. Right hand side grep will filter them.

Comment: +1 for the grep command. I think this is the better solution than the one marked as solution as it list only the ignore Properties!

Comment: This is useful, but you need to be careful - the `-B 1` may mean that not all ignored items are shown (e.g. if multiple files in one folder are ignored), but at least you can get a list of the things that have ignore set on them.

Answer (score 31):

Use:

```
svn pg -R svn:ignore .
```

See Stack Overflow question *[How do I view all ignored patterns set with svn:ignore recursively in an SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252270)*

This shows the relative path with all files ignored by SVN in a working copy of a folder structure. It shows everything recursively.

Comment: I think this is the best approach, because it lists the settings for the `svn:ignore` property and not the others that are irrelevant.

Comment: To be complet, since SVN 1.8, this should be added: `svn propget -R svn:global-ignores .`

Answer (score 11):

If it is Windows and you are using [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN), then right-click on a folder of the working copy, go to the *Subversion* tab and click on *Properties*.

Comment: Careful, this method is not recursive.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it I found after prompting from other answers is to edit the proplist as follows:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

That opens a text editor with the ignore settings for the specified directory (in the above example this is the current directory indicated by .)

Answer (score 3):

Calling `svn proplist` just prints *what* is defined but not *how*. To get additional information, use

```
svn proplist -v
```

which displays additional information (i.e. the contents of the properties).

Answer (score 0):

The list of ignored files is stored in a property. Use [svn proplist](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re22.html) to show the properties of a directory.

Comment: When I do that I just see svn:ignore which tells me that something is being ignored, but not what.

Comment: svn proplist --verbose tells me what is actually ignored.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @dunxd: see my answer below. You have to request the properties verbose.